# ruby cannot assign requested address

Tags: ruby, sockets

I had already created a qt program that listens on a specific port on my server. And it works fine. Now I want to create a simple ruby program to do the same. Right now I just have a simple test server using netcat which establishes a network socket and accepts UDP data (this is Ubuntu server by the way):

```
$ sudo nc -l 1720
```

Now I am just trying to listen on the port in Ruby:

```
# network.rb

require 'socket'

socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.bind('64.xxx.xx.xxx', 1720)
```

This right away raises this exception:

```
network.rb:4:in `bind': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

WHy is it saying the address is not available? All that is there is a netcat socket. The goal is that I will have UDP data coming in from GPRS devices to that port, and then I will have ruby sitting on my ubuntu server listening for that data, then decoding it, and storing it into a postgresql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a server or client?

you used nc, so i guess you are making client.

server is bind

client is connect:

`c = UDPSocket.new`

`c.connect("127.0.0.1", 1111)`

"address is not available" usually as the port is used.

or you can ping the address fisrt to check if the address can be reached

Comment: hmmm thats a good point, whats the difference between server and client here?

Comment: server listening port , and recieves request,then send response.

Comment: client send request to the port,then waiting for the response.

Comment: you already used nc to listen port 1720 , so server was running and port 1720 was occupied.That's why you can't make another server to use same port

Comment: I actually terminated the netcat program and I checked if there is anything listening on port 1720 right now, and there is not. I already fixed the firewall to enable the port (since I already tested this with qt program). However, I still get the same error. i want my ruby program to be the server, not netcat.

Comment: That's strange.Can you ping the addr?

Comment: No because I think ping command requires a host name, not an ip. And I want my server to run on the ip with port 1720, like how I was doing it with netcat. But netcat was just a test server. I want real server in ruby. Basically, this is a server that listens on xxx.xx.xx.xxx:1720 for incoming UDP packets from GSM devices.

Comment: yes ,cannot ping port . you should ping address first. if can reach ,then we come to check the port.

Comment: The address can be reached. And I already used uncomplicated firewall to open the port for udp and tcp connections: sudo ufw allow 1720/udp
sudo ufw allow 1720/tcp. And it was working fine with netcat, I was even able to send some UDP packets to netcat

Comment: The ip isn't your local ip?

Comment: No this is a remote server.

Comment: socket cannot bind to a remote ip

Comment: Well right now I launch terminal and run "ruby server.rb". How do I make this act as a server on my remote server so that it is constantly running and listening on that port? Do I need to turn this to an executable?

Comment: you just need change ip to 127.0.0.1

Comment: and run it on remote machine

Comment: How do I ensure that it is running constantly and constantly listening for UDP packets on that port? I want this to run forever.

Comment: I mean I want the ruby program to run forever, constantly listening on that port, not netcat

Comment: The thing is a ruby script is not an executable. For example, when I ssh into my remote server and run "ruby server.rb", it will run, but when I log out of my server, won't it stop? How do I have my ruby socket server running forever? Must I make a daemon or something?

Comment: all your script codes are above ? you need add action code like:`p s.recvfrom(10)`

Comment: oh okay. use `nohup` ,bash will like this :`nohup ruby server.rb & `

Comment: So that's how a socket server runs all the time (even when logging out of ssh), by using nohup?

Comment: nope. `nohup` is for any command in linux. use it you can keep your process alive even you logout.

Comment: I want this program to run like how mysqld server runs. Is that how mysqld server runs?

Comment: a server machine ,must be active right? your remote server machine of course keeps running.or you cannot connect to it . when a server machine boots up ,mysqld server will boot up by system,then mysqld process will hide to backstage.unless root kills it or this machine powered down, it will run forever. when you creating a process,all actions is actually happening on the remote machine.your monitor just i/o.without nohup,when you closed connection,your account will auto logout.all processes created by this account will be killed.so nohup is small different from the way mysqld runs.

Comment: you can add command into linux startup script .then it is same with mysqld way.

Comment: okay,your UDP server is same with mysqld.... because there is no "mysqld way" ,all is process. your simple script is same with mysqld.mysqld can be killed, can be startuped ,if you don't use nohup,it will shutdown too when you logout. you feel mysqld is different because it was startuped by a never logout machine.

Comment: Hey just to let you know, I did some more research on this and people are saying screen is a better alternative to nohup

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to see you digging deeper on it.keep doing! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error by running:

```
rails s -b 10.0.0.61
```

It turns out that my local IP wasn't 10.0.0.61 and this was causing the error.